# Magento show which files it ignores

Tags: magento

Magento seems to be using "Happy go Lucky" error handling, where all errors in xml files will just cause the xml config file to be ignored. And missing/wrong tags will just be ignored too, sometimes causing Magento to skip parts of the xml file.

But is there any way(A log file or something) which shows exactly what part of the config files Magento skips, and which tags are unknown/wrong. Using Magento 1.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen in Magento, it will throw out the entire XML file if there is invalid XML in it - broken/mismatched tags, erroneous characters, etc. I think it would be somewhat impossible for a xml parser to do any sort of a decent job parsing this out - that's the goal of XML. If my configuration isn't loading, the first think I like to do is go and perform a wellformedness validation on the code, which will show me if I have a problem there.

If there is references to invalid classes, usually it will break. Layout XML is different - it will ignore the block and continue on, which can be a real pain to troubleshoot.

So, to answer your question - no, there isn't a native way to do this. The best way, IMO, is to go and validate it at a third party.

Answer (score 0):

There is logging in Magento, to enable it:

1. Go into your Admin Panel, then System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer
2. Under Log Settings ensure Enabled = Yes
3. This will create two separate logs in **magento root/var/log** (in my case /var/www/html/var/log)
4. Exception.log will hold any errors created using `Mage::LogException($e)`
5. System.log will hold any logging created using `Mage::Log('message')`

You can also create your own log files...if you so wish by

`Mage::Log('message', null, 'my.log');`

This will create a my.log file in the var/log directory.

FYI - I believe the reason Magento handles configuration files in this manner is to protect the rest of the system from an issue with a single extension.

Comment: But that just seems to be the standard php log. I wish there were a log from Magento. It is rather difficult to find skipped xml files from the php log. And there is nothing about unknown tags and other things Magento finds but don't know.

Comment: the standard php log tends to sit under /var/log/apache2 or something like that...this one is under the magento directory. In my case it sits under /var/www/html/var/log. I've updated my answer to make this clearer